# jQuery center multiple dynamic images in different sized containers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've found similar questions but none that answer all the questions I have and I know there must be a simple jQuery answer to this. I've got multiple images that are being dynamically placed in their own containing div that have overflow:hidden, they need to fill their containing divs and be centered(horizontally and vertically) also. The containing divs will be different sizes as well.

So in short:

- multiple different sized images fill and center in containing div.
- containing divs will be different sizes.
- will be used multiple times on a page.
- images fill box proportionally

Hopefully this image helps explain what I'm after.
Click [here](http://jvkdesign.co.nz/center_image_example.jpg) to view the image.

HTML I'm using but can be changed

```
<div class="imageHolder">
    <div class="first SlideImage">
        <img src="..." alt="..."/>
    </div>
    <div class="second SlideImage">
        <img src="..." alt="..."/>
    </div>
    <div class="third SlideImage">
        <img src="..." alt="..."/>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.imageHandler{
    float:left;
    width:764px;
    height:70px;
    margin:1px 0px 0px;
}
.imageHolder .SlideImage{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.imageHolder .SlideImage img{
    position:absolute;
}
.imageHolder .first.SlideImage{
    width:381px;
    height:339px;
    margin-right:1px;
}
.imageHolder .second.SlideImage{margin-bottom:1px;}
.imageHolder .second.SlideImage, .imageHolder .third.SlideImage {
    width: 382px;
    height: 169px;
}
```

Ask me anything if this doesn't make sense,
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a JQuery alternative to my CSS solution:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yczPs/

```
$(".SlideImage").each(function () {
    var container = $(this),
        img = $(this).find("img"),
        margin;
    if (img.width() / container.width() < img.height() / container.height()) {
        img.css("width", container.width());
        margin = -(img.height() * img.width() / container.width() - container.height()) / 2;
        img.css("margin-top", margin);
    } else {
        img.css("height", container.height());
        margin = -(img.width() * img.height() / container.height() - container.width()) / 2;
        img.css("margin-left", margin);
    }
});
```

I just coded that on the fly and haven't done any extensive testing, but it seems to be working fine for the few test cases I threw at it. Let me know if it isn't working properly for you.

Comment: your a legend, works well in the tests that I've tried. Thanks heaps for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplest solution I could come up with :)
Full working example on JSFiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/L3HhX/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.center-trigger').click(function() {
    centerImageInTheContainers();
});

function centerImageInTheContainers() {
    $('.container').each(function(i, v) {
        var container = $(this);
        var myImg = $(this).find('img'); 
        myImg.css('top', calculatePosition(container.height(), myImg.height()));
        myImg.css('left', calculatePosition(container.width(), myImg.width()));
    });
}

function calculatePosition(containerSize, imageSize) {
    return 0 - ((imageSize - containerSize) / 2);
}
```

});

Comment: Hey @Alexus this is great, but just one thing... it doesn't resize to fit the containing box proportionally, if you could work jsfiddle to also do that then this would be perfect! thanks for the help.

Comment: Just realised that I didn't say that too clearly in my question, sorry about that.

Comment: What do you mean by resizing the containing box to fit proportionally? Are we resizing the box or the image?

Comment: Yea sorry I mean the image doesn't resize to fit the containing div proportionally. I want the image to resize.

Comment: Sorry Alexus, I mean resize the image. Click [HERE](http://jvkdesign.co.nz/center_image_example.jpg) to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this can be done with pure CSS, granted that you 1) are OK using background images instead of `<img>` elements, and 2) don't need to support IE8 and below.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6nKKX/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="imageHolder">
  <div class="first SlideImage"></div>
  <div class="second SlideImage"></div>
  <div class="third SlideImage"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:** (The parts relevant to the solution)

```
.imageHolder .SlideImage {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.imageHolder .first.SlideImage {
  background-image: url('...');
}
.imageHolder .second.SlideImage {
  background-image: url('...');
}
etc.
```

Alternatively, you can set the background images inline in the HTML with `<div class="first SlideImage" style="background-image: url('...');"></div>`

Basically, `background-size: cover;` means scale the image until it covers the entire box (cropping whatever is outside of it), and `background-position: center center;` centers the image for you.

Comment: Hey @James unfortunately I can't  place it in a div as a background image as the images are coming to the page dynamically in as <img/> otherwise I would have done it this way. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: you can place it as background image - just use the code like this:

$('.class-of-the-container').css('background', '/image/url/goes/here');

Comment: This won't work either @Alexus as the url for the image will change depending on where the image is being pulled from and I also lose the ability of an alt tag... I like your first approach as it achieves everything I'm after.